# Who is the Culprit

Tags: liars, mystery

One day you were at the hospital that you work at. You have 7 people you are over for their residency, since you are the head pediatric doctor.

There was **Ava**, **Ben**, **Chris**, **Delilah**, **Evan**, **Francine**, and **Gary**. You are all working together to develop a new prosthetic arm for your patients.

You step outside to receive a phone call from your patient, just to come back to find your prosthetic broken! You are very ticked because the head of the hospital (**Jim**) was going to come see your prosthetic on Monday.

You know you will get in trouble, fired, or demoted, since you have only been at the hospital for 2 years. This is only if you cannot prove that Ava, Ben, Chris, Delilah, Evan, Francine, or Gary did it.

To find out who did it, you interrogate each of them (Ava, Ben, Chris, Delilah, Evan, Francine, and Gary).

You know **two of them did it** and that **two of them are lying**.

This is what each of them said:

> Ava: I was cleaning your “Doctor of the Year” award.
>
> Ben: I was fitting Don (17) for a cast.
>
> Chris: I was showing Mary (6) and her mother Lucy (34) to their overnight room.
>
> Delilah: I was taking Savanna's (32) blood work.
>
> Evan: I was packing up to leave for the day, after my 25-hour shift.
>
> Francine: I was making sure our prosthetic could bear the weight of running.
>
> Gary: I was asking Mark (12) how he felt after his surgery.

**Who did it?**

Comment: What is "blood work"?

Comment: It is when you take a patients blood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guilty parties are:

> **Delilah and Francine**

Regarding the statements of the doctors --

```
Ava: I was cleaning your “Doctor of the Year” award.
```

> True, by process of elimination; presumably, innocent.

```
Ben: I was fitting Don (17) for a cast.
```

> True, by process of elimination; presumably, innocent.

```
Chris: I was showing Mary (6) and her mother Lucy (34) to their overnight room.
```

> True, by process of elimination; not in the room, so must be innocent.

```
Delilah: I was taking Savanna's (32) blood work.
```

> False.  You are a pediatric doctor, and the head of other pediatric doctors; your underlings wouldn't be dealing with a 32 year old patient.  Presumably, guilty.

```
Evan: I was packing up to leave for the day, after my 25-hour shift.
```

> True, by process of elimination; presumably, innocent.

```
Francine: I was making sure our prosthetic could bear the weight of running.
```

> False.  The prosthetic is an arm, not a leg; arms don't bear weight during running, so you couldn't test for that.  Presumably, guilty.

```
Gary: I was asking Mark (12) how he felt after his surgery.
```

> True, by process of elimination; presumably, innocent.

Interestingly enough,

> Other than Chris, whose statement would put him out of the room, none of the other doctors' statements serve to actually implicate or exculpate them. Evan, for example, might well have knocked the prosthetic over while collecting his things.  But I think the folks who are lying to give themselves an alibi are intended to be taken as the guilty parties, so that leads us to conclude that -
>
>  **Delilah and Francine** did it.

Comment: You got! You will get a green check and a up-vote soon! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess...

The ones lying are

> Francine, saying she was making sure the prosthetic could bear the weight of running (it's a prosthetic for an *arm* not a leg) and Evan, who said he was packing up to leave but is apparently still here.

The ones who did it are

> Frank, who didn't give any alibi, and Evan, who was disgruntled about his long shift.

It's also possible that

> Francine accidentally broke it while testing if it could bear the weight of running.

Comment: I am not quite convinced by your reasoning for the second liar.  How is "Still Here" a reason for accusation?

Comment: He said he was packing up to go home, so why is he here at the hospital to be interviewed?

Comment: Maybe he just finished packing and was then interviewed. The fact that he was still here won't really hold up in a court of law.

Comment: Yes I guess that's true.

Comment: So close, but not right. :)

Answer (score 2):

Possible clues are:

> Francine is not in your department and therefore either tested another prostetic, misused your prostetic or is lying.
>  There is no answer from Frank.
>  Savannah is too old for being treated by a pediatric. This means Delilah is one of the liars.
>  Being there for two years and fearing to loose your job by breaking a prosthetic makes it unlikely you earned a 'Doctor of the year' award.

This leads me to thinking that the liars are:

> Ava and Delilah

The actors are:

> Francine and Frank

Comment: Also I wonder if the numbers have another meaning. But this might be just a red herring or my imagination

Comment: Interesting thought regarding job insecurities and the doctor of the year award.  I'd be more worried because I had my 7 pediatricians working on a prosthetic that probably should be handled by the prosthetists (or orthotists) in the hospital.

Comment: So close but not it. :)